# Java program doesn't add amounts correctly

Tags: java, methods

So I am still fairly new to java. I have written this but am not sure as to why when I run it, the amounts will not add to what is set in the client.

For example: I enter 500 as starting balance, if I hit deposit, and type 500, and then hit case 3, it should say 1000 but it still says 500. And then If i hit withdraw, it says I have -500.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
package bankaccount;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);       
     System.out.println("Enter your Name: ");
            String cusName = input.nextLine();
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int accNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(100000);
            System.out.println("Enter Initial Balance: ");
            int balance = input.nextInt();
            BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount(cusName, accNo, balance);
            int menu;
            System.out.println("Menu");
            System.out.println("1. Deposit Amount");
            System.out.println("2. Withdraw Amount");
            System.out.println("3. Display Information");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            boolean quit = false;
            do {
                    System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
                    menu = input.nextInt();
                    switch (menu) {
                    case 1:            
                             System.out.print("Enter depost amount:");
                             Money.amount = input.nextInt(); 
                             b1.getDeposit(); 

                            break;

                    case 2:
                             System.out.println("Current Account Balance=" + b1.getBalance());
                             System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount:");
                             Money.amount = input.nextInt();
                             b1.getWithdraw();

                            break;

                    case 3:
                            b1.display();
                            break;
                    case 4:
                            quit = true;
                            break;
                    }
            } while (!quit);
    }
```

---

```
public class Money
{

public static int accountNumber, balance=0;
static int amount;

static String name;
public void setDeposit(int amount) {   

            balance = balance + amount;   
    }
public int getDeposit()
{

            balance = balance + amount;
            if (amount < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
                                    return 1; 

}
 public void setBalance(int b)
 {
     b = balance;
 }
 public int getBalance()
 {
     return balance;
 }

 public void setWithdraw(int amount)  {


            balance = balance - amount;
    }
 public int getWithdraw()
 {
            balance = balance - amount;
     if (balance < amount) 
     {
                    System.out.println("Not enough funds.");
                    return 1;
            }
           else if (amount < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                    return 1;}
                    else 
                             return 0;
 }
```

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class BankAccount extends Money {
    static String name;
    public static int balance, amount, acctNum;
    Money customerMoney;


    BankAccount(String name, int accNo, int bal) {
            this.name = name;
            this.acctNum = accNo;
            this.balance = bal;
            this.customerMoney = new Money();
    }
            void display() {
            System.out.println("Name:" + name);
            System.out.println("Account No:" + acctNum);
            System.out.println("Balance:" + balance);

    }

    void displayBalance() {
            System.out.println("Balance:" + balance);
    }
    public Money getMoney(){
          return this.customerMoney;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how do you actually deposit money to the `BankAccount`?

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger?

Comment: IMO, this inheritance is iffy. This doesn't really follow the `base class IS A parent class`. A bank account isn't really money.

Comment: what if I enter balance as `23.34`. Always have balance, amount in decimal point...

Comment: Why are getDeposit and GetWithdraw changing balance?

Comment: I am supposed to have all of the math in separate classes. However, the deposit method does not seem to work, nor does the balance ever update from what is set initially

Comment: Constructors and instance methods shouldn't be updating `static` fields as you might want to have more than one account in your bank one day.  Currently you are assuming there can be only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove all the `public static int` variables that you are using. These are going to cause confusion because it's much harder to follow what their values are as the program executes. Best to encapsulate your logic into `BankAccount` using private variables and public methods to modify them.

I would, personally, eliminate the `Money` class from your code. It's just going to cause confusion and with your simplified logic is not required. Let's assume the account holds some arbitrary count of 'money' but there is no real-life money actually backing it up - (kind of like real life, it's just 'numbers on a screen' right?) - in this case we wouldn't need the `Money` class, just an `int` for our `BankAccount`'s `balance`.

Without trying to make too many changes to your underlying functionality, I rewrote as the below two classes:

A `BankAccount` class:

```
package banking;

public class BankAccount {

    /**
     * The balance of this account. <br/>
     * Assumes integer money (Floating point math is horrible and who really
     * needs pesky pence or cents right?!)
     */
    private int balance;
    /**
     * The account number
     */
    private final int acctNum;
    /**
     * Name of the account holder
     */
    private final String name;

    /**
     * Construct our basic account with an account number, account holder and
     * starting balance.
     *
     * @param name
     * @param accNo
     * @param bal
     */
    public BankAccount(String name, int accNo, int bal) {
        this.name = name;
        this.acctNum = accNo;
        this.balance = bal;
    }

    /**
     * Make a deposit to this account by adding a fixed sum to the existing
     * balance. <br/>
     *
     * @param amount
     */
    public void deposit(int amount) {
        if (amount <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot deposit zero or less");
        } else {
            this.balance += amount;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make a withdrawal from this account by subtracting a fixed amount from
     * the existing balance. <br/>
     *
     * @param amount
     */
    public void withdraw(int amount) {
        if (amount > balance) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient Funds");
        } else if (amount <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot withdraw zero or less");
        } else {
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the account holder name.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current account balance.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the account identifier for this account.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getAcctNum() {
        return acctNum;
    }

    /**
     * Debug print method.
     */
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name:" + name);
        System.out.println("Account No:" + acctNum);
        System.out.println("Balance:" + balance);
    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
package banking;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your Name: ");
        String customerName = input.nextLine();

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int acctNo = randomGenerator.nextInt(100000);

        System.out.println("Enter Initial Balance: ");
        int balance = input.nextInt();

        BankAccount acct = new BankAccount(customerName, acctNo, balance);

        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Deposit Amount");
        System.out.println("2. Withdraw Amount");
        System.out.println("3. Display Information");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");

        boolean quit = false;
        int menu;
        do {
            final int transaction;
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
            menu = input.nextInt();
            switch (menu) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Enter depost amount:");
                    transaction = input.nextInt();
                    acct.deposit(transaction);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Current Account Balance=" + acct.getBalance());
                    System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount:");
                    transaction = input.nextInt();
                    try {
                        acct.withdraw(transaction);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iaEx) {
                        System.out.println(iaEx.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    acct.display();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!quit);
    }
}
```

This is still far from perfect, but I feel it's easier to follow for having the static variables and `Money` class removed.

Comment: Thanks, this helped it showed me where I made a mistake in my own code!

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem is at statement **`balance=0`**

```
public static int accountNumber, balance=0;
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Every time when you are going to insert amount, your balance is **ZERO**.

You should have used `setDeposit(input.nextInt())`

In `public void setBalance(int b)`, `b = balance;` should have been `balance = b;`

Also, your `amount`, `balance` variables should be `Float` instead of `int` as `balance`/`amount` can be `23434.22`.

Comment: I took off the balance = 0, but it still won't update the totals in the getDeposit an Balance. They stay the same as the first entry. However, the withdraw actually takes out the amount.

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten : let me check your full code...

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten : in `getDeposit()` can you print balance and amount before and after line `balance = balance + amount;`

Comment: Tried this and it still says 500 if I set the initial balance to 500

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten : What you get for balance and amount? tell me two different numbers.. You said 500, but for what?

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten : Write `System.out.println("amount=="+amount+", balance=="+balance)` before and after and let me know what you get before and after.... just copy paste that line.

Comment: 'amount==0.0, balance==500.0
    amount==0.0, balance==500.0'

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten : in `public void setBalance(int b)` did you put `balance=b` instead of `b=balance`? Do that and let me know if you get same...

Comment: yes i did, and it still does the same thing. Deposit withdraw method still seems to work fine, te balance just isn't updating in te display method or deposit metod

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten : write `System.out.println("Current Account Balance=" + b1.getBalance());` in `case 1` at the start and let me know what you get...

Comment: I ended up getting it to work. I had to change ' System.out.println("Balance:" + balance);' to 'System.out.println("Your Current Account Balance:" + Money.getBalance());' and it worked.

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten :  That is what I meant. you should use `b1.getBalance()` instead of `Money.getBalance()` as b1 is the object that you are referring to...

Comment: @RickyMcQuesten : Good to know that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems with the code e.g. none of your fields should be static, but the main one is that you have multiple duplicated fields.

e.g. In Money you have

```
public static int accountNumber, balance=0;
static int amount;

static String name;
```

and in BankAccount you have

```
static String name;
public static int balance, amount, acctNum;
Money customerMoney;
```

which means you have multiple fields called `name`, `balance` and `amount`. Some of the code uses the first group of fields and some of the code uses the second. You also have a `customerMoney` which is not updated directly.

To avoid confusion I suggest you have each field be non-static and in only one place.  Remove the `customerMoney` as you might be tempted to use it ;)